# AJAX with WordPress HTTP API

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm new to php and stuck in my tracks here, so any help is appreciated. I've written a few functions in a JS file to render and update a gallery view for a WordPress template I made. From the `updateGallery()` function, I make an AJAX call after pressing a submit button on the page, but am receiving a "parsererror."

`Arguments(3) [{…}, "parsererror", SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0 at parse (<anonymous>)
at Ut (https://…, callee: ƒ, Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ]`

I tried the code for the API request directly in my WP template to render a response and it worked as expected, but when I try to incorporate my script I get the error and I can't figure out what's causing it.

**JS**

```
function updateGallery() {

    var county = $("#county").val();

    jQuery(".galleryGrid").fadeOut("fast", function() {
        console.log("ajax request");
        jQuery(".galleryGrid").html("").hide();
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            dataType : "JSON",
            url : ajax.url,
            data : { 
                action: "get_gallery_data",
                county_id : county
            },
            error: function(response, error) {
                console.log(arguments);
                alert("Failed because: " + error);
            },
            success : function(response) {
                if(response.type === "success") {
                    console.log("Success")
                    renderGrid(response.data);
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

**PHP**

```
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_get_gallery_data", "get_gallery_data");
add_action("wp_ajax_get_gallery_data", "get_gallery_data");

function get_gallery_data() {

    $county_id = $_REQUEST[county_id];

    $base_api_url = "https://some.api.com/";

    $filters = array(
        "field" => "field_153",
        "operator" =>"is",
        "value" => $county_id
    );

    $filters_url = rawurlencode(json_encode($filters));

    $api_url = $base_api_url."?filters=".$filters_url;


    $request = wp_remote_get($api_url, array(
        "headers" => array(
            "Application-Id" => "5xxxxxx",
            "REST-API-KEY" => "0xxxxxx",
        ),
    ));

    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($request);
    $output = json_decode($body, true);
    echo $output;

    die();
};
```

Comment: To output json you use `json_encode()` on array http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php. If `wp_remote_retrieve_body($request)` returns json string....just echo that

Comment: Yes exactly, like @charlietfl said, you need to use `json_encode()`.

Comment: @charlietfl That's what I did originally and got no response. For some reason this is the only way to receive a response albeit an error.

Comment: Inspect the actual response in the success callback by logging it to console. If nothing happens inspect the whole request in browser dev tools network and look at the response body to see what it actually contains

Answer (score 0):

```
 $output = json_decode($body, true);
```

//Change

```
 $output = json_encode($body, true);
```